# Facing issue with loading a .pyc file from a separate script

Tags: python

I have a .pyc file with code:

```
def myfunc(in_str = "Hello World"):
    print(in_str)
```

I try to run it from a separate code like this:

```
import marshal
s = open('script2.cpython-37.pyc', 'rb')
s.seek(12)  # Also tried s.seek(8) here

code_obj = marshal.load(s)
exec(code_obj)
myfunc()
myfunc("Testing from script4")
```

The error I am getting:

```
(base) C:\Users\ashish\Desktop\code_20210128\2>python script4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script4.py", line 5, in <module>
    code_obj = marshal.load(s)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Please let me know if am doing something wrong and how to fix this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the seek(12) or seek(8)?

Comment: First 4 bytes are for signaling a 'magic number'.
Next 4 bytes holding a modification timestamp.